# Google sheets won't format time date correctly

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, formatting, locale

My Google Sheets is currently set to UK London GMT

I have some data that is needed in UK format and other data that is needed in US format within the same sheet.

I'm using date time as dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss and have been trying to convert this to US yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

When formatting the UK date time to as text and using this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+)", "$3/$2/$1"))
```

It should be converting for me however is stays the same.

I have also tried simply copying and pasting in a new column with the intention of changing format from within formatting settings but when pasting it seems to randomly select different formats in some rows using / instead of - and in other rows returning a number instead of date time.

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: Can you share an example of the sheet you are working with? Also, the original (UK) dates are in plain text or formatted on the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXT(A2, "e-m-d h:mm:ss")
```

[image]